# Include Hortonworks respository in Spring Boot executable jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, apache-spark, hbase

I'm using the shc-core dependency from the Hortonworks repository in a Spring Boot application, with the repository declared in the pom.xml file as follows:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.hortonworks</id>
        <name>Hortonworks Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The dependency that I'm adding from this repository is this:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.hortonworks</groupId>
      <artifactId>shc-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11</version>
  </dependency>
```

I'm using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to build an executable jar file. But when I  `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage`, it is not packaging the shc-core jar in the Spring Boot executable jar file.

I've already tried the system scope with `<includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>` configuration enabled. But that didn't work either.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding in pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and

run::

mvn clean compile install assembly:single